# element fill rest of page after a top margin

Tags: html, css

On this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/TechplexEngineer/nFZ8e/1/

How could one get the blocks element to fill the rest of the sidebar?

Thanks,
Blake

Edit: How can I make it so when I re-size the window the scrolled area remains stuck to the bottom. (No red shows beneath)

http://jsfiddle.net/TechplexEngineer/nFZ8e/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to your sidebar, and set `padding-bottom: 9999px;` on your block-level element that you want to extend all the way down.

http://jsfiddle.net/nFZ8e/3/

Comment: You don't need the padding, just a `height: 100%` will do.

Comment: @William: If the `#block` element extends further than `height: 100%`, you want it to grow the parent: http://jsfiddle.net/nFZ8e/5/

Comment: @Joseph Silber is there a way to scroll this overflow?

Comment: @TechplexEngineer: You'll have to wrap your content in another element, set it to `overflow: hidden`, and set your sidebar to `overflow:auto`: http://jsfiddle.net/nFZ8e/8/

Comment: @Joseph Silber How about more like this. http://jsfiddle.net/TechplexEngineer/nFZ8e/7/ I only want the bottom part to scroll. Not the whole side panel.

Comment: @TechplexEngineer: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to accomplish. Are you not happy with the way your fiddle looks? What would you like changed?

Comment: @Joseph Silber I finally got it. Have a look. Try changing the size of the result area. I was looking for a css way to do this. http://jsfiddle.net/TechplexEngineer/nFZ8e/9/

Comment: @TechplexEngineer: You shouldn't have to look for `blocks` in the DOM every time the browser resizes, you should cache it. You can also simplify your code: http://jsfiddle.net/nFZ8e/11/

Comment: @Joseph Silber For some reason http://jsfiddle.net/nFZ8e/11/ doesn't work the console says that the $function isn't defined. I changed it to $(document).ready and it worked. Thank you very much. http://jsfiddle.net/TechplexEngineer/nFZ8e/12/

Comment: @TechplexEngineer: You're right. My bad. That should have been `$(function()...` which is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function()...`.